# unable to plot graph matplotlib in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib

im using a new laptop and transfer my old data to the new one. however my matplotlib doesnt want to plot the graph in the new window but it works in the old one. i have check the installation of matplotlib and everything and no idea what is going wrong

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

#creating list
pd = {0.05, 0.34, 0.56, 0.5, 0.7,0.2, 0.36, 0.54, 0.65, 0.456}
#len of the lists
d = len (pd)
print (d)

x = range(d)
bwidth= 1/1.25
pl.figure(1,figsize =(7,5))
pl.bar(x,pd,bwidth, color = "red")
pl.show()
```

and this is the error that i got

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-b7b3df1db861> in <module>()
     12 bwidth= 1/1.25
     13 pl.figure(1,figsize =(7,5))
---> 14 pl.bar(x,pd,bwidth, color = "red")
     15 pl.show()

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in 
 bar(*args, **kwargs)
 2625                       mplDeprecation)
 2626     try:
->2627         ret = ax.bar(*args, **kwargs)
 2628     finally:
 2629         ax._hold = washold

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in 
 inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  1708                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
  1709                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
->1710             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  1711         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
  1712         if pre_doc is None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in 
bar(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2154             elif orientation == 'horizontal':
   2155                 r.sticky_edges.x.append(l)
-> 2156             self.add_patch(r)
   2157             patches.append(r)
   2158 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in 
add_patch(self, p)
   1832         if p.get_clip_path() is None:
   1833             p.set_clip_path(self.patch)
-> 1834         self._update_patch_limits(p)
   1835         self.patches.append(p)
   1836         p._remove_method = lambda h: self.patches.remove(h)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in 
_update_patch_limits(self, patch)
   1852         vertices = patch.get_path().vertices
   1853         if vertices.size > 0:
-> 1854             xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)
   1855             if patch.get_data_transform() != self.transData:
   1856                 patch_to_data = (patch.get_data_transform() -

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in 
get_patch_transform(self)
    720 
    721     def get_patch_transform(self):
--> 722         self._update_patch_transform()
    723         return self._rect_transform
    724 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in 
_update_patch_transform(self)
    713         width = self.convert_xunits(self._width)
    714         height = self.convert_yunits(self._height)
--> 715         bbox = transforms.Bbox.from_bounds(x, y, width, height)
    716         rot_trans = transforms.Affine2D()
    717         rot_trans.rotate_deg_around(x, y, self.angle)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py in 
from_bounds(x0, y0, width, height)
    802         *width* and *height* may be negative.
    803         """
--> 804         return Bbox.from_extents(x0, y0, x0 + width, y0 + height)
    805 
    806     @staticmethod

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'set'
```

im using matplotlib 2.1.0 version and Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You cannot plot sets. In the code above `pd` is a set, not a list.

You can convert to a list first before plotting,

```
plt.bar(x, list(pd), bwidth, color = "red")
```